# Hibernate is not auto-creating a table in MySql that does not exist in the DB but I not get any errors

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

Sorry guys, I know there are many solutions for this problem but I tried everything. I am using Java 17, 2.5.5 spring version. My application connects to mysql but cannot create the table. I tried every possible solution but it is not working . Whether the problem belongs to the side hibernate or there is something else? I tried 100 different application properties but none was good for me.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")

public class Employee {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Column(name = "firstName")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "lastName")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "emailId")
private String emailId;

public Employee(){

}
public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String emailId){
    super();
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.emailId = emailId;
}
```

}

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/employeeSystem
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>SpringAngular</groupId>
    <artifactId>EmployeeCRUD</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>EmployeeCRUD</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository <Employee, Long> {
}
```

Comment: What happens when you set it to `create` instead of `update` (I expect the db of a demo project does not contain important records)? Does it get created then?

Comment: Nothing happend

Comment: Are you using `@EntityScan` in your spring boot project?

Comment: No, I do not use this. Changed Entity to EntityScan but it didnt worked

Comment: `@EntityScan` is not a substitute for `@Entity` but a Spring Boot annotation you should place on your configuration class. Read up on `@EnableJpaRepositories` and `@EntityScan` as I suspect that your entity is not detected by Spring.

Comment: Somehow it worked! Thanks